# Oracle WebLogic Server over Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, weblogic11g

I have a running on premises implementation of WLS 11g which runs on Solaris VMs in an Oracle Super Cluster (JDK 1.7). We want to lift & shift some workload into the cloud and would like to know if this exact configuration can be replicated over Azure in order to deploy WLS managed servers. Our applications is JEE with JSF, some JMS and EJBs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely deploy WLS on Azure but not on Solaris as this is not an endorsed distribution. If your application is not OS dependent though, you can choose from a wide array of Linux distributions (Oracle Linux, CentOS, RHEL, SUSE, etc.). The rest of your JEE framework is perfectly compatible with the Azure platform as well.